# Json code snippet

Tags: .net, json

I want add JSON for website: http://maybomchim.vn but it is not working.
I am new to JSON & am trying to figure out stuff, any help is highly appreciated. I am loading a JSON object from JSON external file that has a very complex structure like arrays, JSON object & nested JSON objects.

I create a dynamic .NET object & assigned deserialized object to it, something like

```
dynamic test = JSSerializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
```

I need to convert the JSON object to a text file. How do i approach after JSON string is deserialized??

Comment: Welcome.  Please provide an example of what you are trying to do so we can better help you.

Comment: You already have your object as string in `json` variable. You can serialize `test` again, but first you need to strong type it. Create a c# class that has the same properties than the json, so you will be able to deserealize it to an object and later you can serialize it again. Dynamic is not serializable.